# "made rather a business of..."

Tags: phrase-meaning

> In twos and threes the rest of the group took their leave, too. Cho **made rather a business of** fastening the catch on her bag before leaving, her long dark curtain of hair swinging forwards to hide her face, but her friend stood beside her, arms folded, clicking her tongue, so that Cho had little choice but to leave with her.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix</sub>

Is "made rather a business of" a set phrase? I can't find it in any dictionaries. I guess here it means: Cho deliberately procrastinated by slowly fastening the catch on her bag before leaving. Is this understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also didn't manage to find it in dictionaries. The meaning is exactly as you described it.

I found an instance of **quite a business** on Google Books:

> “Why I came here in the first place,” Blair said, bending a large paper clip out of shape as, years ago, he would have **made quite a business of** lighting a cigarette, “is an easy question."